# How to make program auto start when system start in Ubuntu 17.0.4

Tags: files, startup

I'm confusion in the latest **Ubuntu 17.04 Gnome**, I even cannot find the file `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`. If the system has it, I can add my command in it. Then the command will run once the system start. But since this file is non-exist,how should I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

To run an application when the system start, put your `.desktop` file in `/etc/xdg/autostart`

```
/etc/xdg/autostart/programtostart.desktop
```

[xdg-autostart manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/xdg-autostart.1.html)

Comment: or if not found you can set it for the user at `/home/username/.config/autostart/programtostart.desktop .. but im on 16.04 so maybe its different in 17.04

Comment: I can also do it in the GUI under `Start-Settings-Session and Startup` in the `Application Autostart` tab

Answer (score 1):

You can use the crontab for this if it should be simply done at reboot, you can do it in your own crontab or in other users crontab, depending on which you need to use `sudo` respectively:

```
sudo crontab -e -u <username>
```

If you are editing your own crontab you can omit `sudo` and the `-u <username>`. Simply adding a line like this suffices:

```
@reboot    /full/path/to/script
```

Hope it helps, for further reading see the [manpage for the `crontab` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/crontab) .