# Executing an sh script on Ubuntu boot

Tags: boot, scripts, 17.04

I've been trying for some time to execute my script, UbuntuBootScript.sh, every time Ubuntu boots up.
The script is located at the following path: `/home/network/scripts/UbuntuBootScript.sh`
I have attempted at telling ubuntu to run the script every time it boots, through the /etc/rc.local directory, who's content currently is:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
/home/network/scripts/UbuntuBootScript.sh
exit 0
```

Content of UbuntuBootScript.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash
sh openWindows.sh
sh startServers.sh
exit 0
```

Both called scripts function correctly if executed individually.

Up on rebooting ubuntu, UbuntuBootScript.sh seems to not be executed, since the desired functionality does not occur.
It looks like either something is not well written on rc.local, or the boot script rc.local is somehow disabled?, because the script itself DOES work if manually executed.
I need to fix this issue. Assistance is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/984771

Comment: Interesting, I'm not sure I understand how the suggestion on that thread works though.
If I just drop my .sh file on that directory, should it be run on boot?

Comment: you can have different crontabs, depending on which user you call the `crontab -e` command, if you call it from root you edit roots crontab, if you call it from your user you create a crontab for your user for example regarding my answer on that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to run commands at startup is to add them to `/etc/rc.local` but you need to make these commands executable your best bet is to use [this](https://gist.github.com/Darth4212/6330a6b005c6ef1f83f2023c35dbdda3) script, what this script does is adds a link to the selected file in `/bin/` allowing for it to be executed where you want.

What you should do is download the script and place it in a directory, it has to be `~/Scripts` and then open a terminal and then run `cd ~/Scripts` then `sudo chmod +x makeex.sh` and then `sudo ln -r -s makeex.sh /bin/`

And then `cd` into whatever directory UbuntuBootScript.sh is stored in and run `makeex.sh UbuntuBootScript.sh` and then edit `/ect/rc.local` and add `UbunutBootScript.sh` to it.